# Java web services integration in existing applications

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, cxf, axis

i have been looking at various solutions to implement web services in java.

What I am looking for is a solution that is easy to integrate in existing web applications.

I have a web applications for which i would like to offer certain functionalities as web services (also provide security, access restriction etc.).

I have been looking at **CXF, Axis2, Metro,** but have not found a lot of useful information on using in existing apps.

What would be a good solution in my case?

Comment: Look into if your web container provides any features for you to use directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Spring contract-first web services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/), especially if you're already a Spring user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [JAX-WS RI](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/UsersGuide.html) (reference implementation) as well. One quick way to integrate it is [via the WSServlet](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/jaxws-war.html).